# Saving values of Excel cross-sheet formulas to csv

Tags: excel, vba, csv, formula

Using other threads, I distilled a VBA script to save each sheet in an Excel workbook to a separate CSV file.  One of my sheets contains formulas over data on another sheet.  The cells with those formulas are saving as `REF!`s, and I haven't been able to figure out how to use `.Value` to fix the problem (I just want to export the values to CSV).

Here is the core of my script (I omitted some `vars defns` and other setup/cleanup code)

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(strApp+sFullPath)
oBook.Application.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
For Each objws In oBook.Sheets  
  objws.Copy  
  With objws.UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  sheetName = Replace(objws.Name, " ", "")
  toName = strApp & sFilename & "-" & sheetName & ".csv"
  objws.SaveAs toName, 6
  oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False  
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it to values before you copy

```
With objws.UsedRange
   .Value = .Value
End With
objws.Copy
```

You can then in the end close the source workbook without saving.